# How Can I get the real name of an image from a url

Tags: c#, webrequest

I have the next url about an image:

```
https://i.discogs.com/HE17wcv1sG6NDK1WcVyoQjSqUGDZva3SYvm6vXoCMOo/rs:fit/g:sm/q:90/h:600/w:600/czM6Ly9kaXNjb2dz/LWRhdGFiYXNlLWlt/YWdlcy9SLTk2OTY5/NjktMTQ4NDkzNzkw/Ni00MDcyLmpwZWc.jpeg
```

If I open the url with the navigator and then I press de right button to save this image in my hard disc the name solved by the navigator for this file image is distinct.
How can i get the last name of the file in c#?

Comment: The real name is _"Ni00MDcyLmpwZWc.jpeg"_. That's it. I'm assuming this is not what you want?

Comment: For your specific link, I notice that there is a "Content-Disposition" header that states the filename is _"R-9696969-1484937906-4072.jpg"_ - is that what you are expecting?

Comment: I think yes. How Can I do that?

Comment: How are you currently downloading the file with .NET?

Comment: .Net => WebClient client = new WebClient(); client.DownloadFile(new Uri(url), pathDestination);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're set on using `WebClient` then you can download the data into memory, check for the Content-Disposition header, and then change the filename accordingly. I've added commented out parts that you can use instead of their synchronous counterparts if you're using this method asynchronously.

```cs
// private static async Task DownloadImageAsync(string url, string folder)
private static void DownloadImage(string url, string folder)
{
    var uri = new Uri(url);
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(uri.AbsolutePath);
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    // byte[] fileData = await client.DownloadDataTaskAsync(url);
    byte[] fileData = client.DownloadData(url);

    string disposition = client.ResponseHeaders.Get("Content-Disposition"); // try to get the disposition
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(disposition) // check it has a value
        && ContentDispositionHeaderValue.TryParse(disposition, out var parsedDisposition) // check it can be parsed
        && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(parsedDisposition.FileName)) // check a filename is specified
    {
        fileName = parsedDisposition.FileName.Trim('"'); // replace the normal filename with the parsed one
    }
    // await File.WriteAllBytesAsync(Path.Combine(folder, fileName), fileData);
    File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(folder, fileName), fileData);
}
```

Usage: `DownloadImage(myurl, @"C:\Users\Me\Desktop");`

---

That said, `WebClient` is a bit old-fashioned and you should probably use `HttpClient` for newer developments:

```cs
private static async Task DownloadImageAsync(string url, string folder)
{
    var uri = new Uri(url);
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(uri.AbsolutePath);

    using var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(url);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition?.FileName))
    {
        fileName = response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Trim('"');
    }

    using var outputFile = File.Create(Path.Combine(folder, fileName));
    await response.Content.CopyToAsync(outputFile);
}
```

Usage: `await DownloadImageAsync(myurl, @"C:\Users\Me\Desktop");`

Microsoft recommend using a single static instance of `HttpClient` throughout your application ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-7.0)). This does have [pitfalls](https://josef.codes/you-are-probably-still-using-httpclient-wrong-and-it-is-destabilizing-your-software/) though, so depending on your application, you might want to look into using [IHttpClientFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests), which works to solve the issues that come from using a static `HttpClient`.